# Poisson Race Problem

Tags: poisson-distribution

Let $X \sim Pois(\lambda)$ and $Y \sim Pois(\mu)$ be independent random variables that follow two different Poisson distributions, with $\lambda < \mu$, then we have $P(X-Y \geq 0) \leq e^{-(\sqrt\mu-\sqrt\lambda)^2}$, as demonstrated on the Wikipedia with the following link
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Poisson_races.

My question is what is the lower-bound and the upper bound of the probability $P(X-Y > 0)$.

Comment: Did you mean to change from $\ge$ to $\gt$ between the link and your question?  With a discrete distribution that is important.  With $\gt$ the lower bound is clearly $0$ when $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are very small and $X,Y$ are both likely to be $0$.  The upper bound is $1$ when they are very different.  What more do you want?

Comment: Oh, let me clarify this problem in this way. I want to know the lower bound and the upper bound when $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are known. Precisely, I want to know how to use $\lambda$ and $\mu$  to express the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

The bounds provided in the Wikipedia article

$$\frac{e^{-(\sqrt{\mu} - \sqrt{\lambda})^2}}{(\lambda + \mu)^2} - \frac{e^{-(\lambda + \mu)}}{2 \sqrt{\lambda \mu}} - \frac{e^{-(\lambda + \mu)}}{4 \lambda \mu} \le \Pr[X - Y \ge 0] \le e^{-(\sqrt{\mu} - \sqrt{\lambda})^2} \tag{1}$$

presumably can be modified as desired by noting $$\Pr[X - Y \ge 0] = \Pr[X - Y = 0] + \Pr[X - Y > 0], \tag{2}$$ then computing $$\Pr[X = Y] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \Pr[X = k]\Pr[Y = k] = e^{-(\lambda + \mu)} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda \mu)^k}{(k!)^2}. \tag{3}$$  This sum can be written in terms of a modified Bessel function of the first kind, or a hypergeometric function:

$$\Pr[X = Y] = e^{-(\lambda + \mu)} I_0 (2 \sqrt{\lambda \mu}) = e^{-(\lambda + \mu)} {}_0 F_1 (1; \lambda \mu). \tag{4}$$  Subtracting $(4)$ from $(1)$ results in a bound for $\Pr[X - Y > 0]$.  If $(4)$ is undesirable because of the use of non-elementary functions, a looser lower bound can be obtained by truncating the series $(3)$ to a finite number of terms.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.